# joomla Execute request to view com_k2 item in joomla template

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

I need execute com_k2 in my template.

I would execute request or include component com_k2 at my `template/index.php` site e.g. `http://mydomainurl.com/index.php?product_id=2`

`/public_html/templates/mytemplate/index.php` code:

```
if(isset($_GET['product_id']) !=''){

Get com_k2 item Execute request like /index.php?option=com_k2&view=item&id=100

} else { // my default template code… }
```

COM_K2 source file: https://github.com/joomlaworks/k2/blob/master/administrator/components/com_k2/models/item.php

Comment: You're supposed to create a menu item and assign a component to that menu item. Do not start editing your template index.php file like this. It's not how a Joomla works

Comment: no i need to include product_page in my index.php // anymore